# How do I get the directory name of the file that's being executed, even when I'm executing the file from outside of it's directory?

Tags: python, python-os

I am not looking for `os.getcwd()`, since that seems to return your location at the moment you're executing the script.

If I am in `/Users/jo/Documents/`, and I execute the script: `/Users/scripts/python/myScript.py`, what can I execute from within my script, in order to check that `/Users/scripts/python/siblingScript.py` exists?

So I was thinking that I would get the directory name of the file that's being executed first, and then call `(...).exists("siblingScript.py")` on it.

How would I get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details are a little different depending on whether you're executing `/Users/scripts/python/myScript.py` by its full path name or by a relative path. But in any case you can use functions in os.path. You *probably* want `isfile()` rather than `exists()`.

```
>>> import os.path
>>> p = os.path.dirname("/Users/scripts/python/myScript.py")
>>> p
'/Users/scripts/python'
>>> f = os.path.join(p, "siblingScript.py")
>>> f
'/Users/scripts/python/siblingScript.py'
>>> os.path.isfile(f)
True
```

If you're executing myScript.py by a relative path, use abspath().

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/msherrill/test/Users/jo/Documents'
>>> p = os.path.dirname("../../scripts/python/myScript.py")
>>> p
'../../scripts/python'
>>> os.path.abspath(p)
'/home/msherrill/test/Users/scripts/python'
```

You should read the [Python os.path docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html) specific to your version of Python. There are some application-specific, subtle details.